# Using python models in Django Models

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

The following is my models.py for my Django app:

```
from django.db import models
from djorm_pgarray.fields import ArrayField
from djorm_expressions.models import ExpressionManager

class Device(models.Model):
    child_devices = ArrayField(dbtype='text')
    ....
```

So basically, I'm using a python model called "djorm_pgarray" to use Postgresql's ARRAY datatype in my Django Models.

Obviously I installed the packages typing within virtual environment:

```
pip install djorm-ext-pgarray
```

When I sync and run the Django server and try to load the admin page, then I get this error:

```
   ImportError at /admin/
    No module named djorm_pgarray
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://agile-woodland-9781.herokuapp.com/admin/
    Django Version: 1.6.2
    Exception Type: ImportError
    Exception Value:    
    No module named djorm_pgarray
    Exception Location: /app/app_search/models.py in <module>, line 2
    Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
    Python Version: 2.7.6
    Python Path:    
    ['/app',
     '/app/.heroku/python/bin',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg',
     '/app',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python27.zip',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
    Server time:    Sat, 19 Apr 2014 17:52:35 +0000
```

How can I import and use python modules in Django models?

Thanks

Comment: I see you're using heroku. Did you remember to add djorm-ext-pgarray to your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: Was the virtualenv activated when you installed with pip?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that:

1. `pip install djorm-ext-pgarray` is executed from within your virtual env
2. `pip freeze > requirements.txt` updates your file properly
3. the changes to `requirements.txt` are committed to git and properly pushed to Heroku

Comment: Had this same issue, was indeed a matter of not having a library installed.